# Problems with division in C#

Tags: c#

How can I check if 204 / 5 is greater than 200 / 5? I experienced difficulty when I attempted this, using both floating-point and decimal math.

Comment: (float)200/(float)5 < (float)204/(float)5

Answer (score 15):

Using float or decimal *will* work... but you need to perform the *arithmetic* in floating point by making at least one of the operands decimal/float/double:

```
decimal x = ((decimal) 204) / 5;
decimal y = ((decimal) 200) / 5;

if (x > y) // Yes!
```

Or use floating point literals:

```
decimal x = 204m / 5;
decimal y = 200m / 5;
```

It doesn't matter *which* operand is floating point:

```
decimal x = 204 / 5m;
decimal y = 200 / 5m;
```

float/double work just as well:

```
double x = 204d / 5;
double y = 200d / 5;
```

So, what's going on if you just use 204 / 5? Well, consider this statement:

```
double x = 204 / 5;
```

The compiler doesn't use the type of the variable to work out the type of the right hand side. It works out that the right hand side is just an integer, obtained by dividing two integers. The *result* is then converted into a `double` and assigned to `x`. The problem is that the arithmetic is done *purely with integers* whereas you want the conversion to floating point to be performed earlier, so that you can get a floating point result.

Answer (score 5):

Appending a `.0` or an `f` to any number forces the language to interpret that number as a floating-point decimal:

- `204` is an integer,
- `204f` is a single-precision floating-point decimal and
- `204.0` is a double-precision floating-point decimal.

Therefore, `204/5` returns an integer `40` and `204.0/5` returns a double-precision float `40.8`.

```
if (204.0/5 > 200.0/5) {
    // stuff
}
```

Or, you could take the mathematically-simpler route:

```
if (204 > 200) {
    // because you're dividing both of them by 5
}
```

Comment: CPU doesn't recast.  It just tells the compiler what kind of code to general to deal with the numbers (as integers, floats, doubles, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((204.0 / 5.0) > (200.0 / 5.0)) {
    //do stuff!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, when you try to calculate `204/5`, it is exactly calculating `int 204 divides int 5`, the result is also an `int` in C#. You can try `204m/5`, you will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((float)(204) / 5) > ((float)(200) / 5))
{
//Enter code here
}
else
{
//Enter code here
}
```